# Iterate with .each after jQuery UI Sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using this:

```
$('#save-button').click(function(event) {     
     $('#element-destination li').not('.option').each(function(index) { 

       // do stuff

     });
});
```

To iterate through a list.  Now that I've made the list sortable with jQuery UI, the code doesn't pickup the NEW order.  Instead it sees the original order without fail.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: depends where you run that code. Need to provide more context and what your goals are

Comment: I dunno, I think it's clear.  I have an unordered list which I have made sortable with drag and drop via jQuery ui.  This code works fine for the list as-is, but doesn't get the new order once the user has changed it with the sortable functioning.

Comment: The code is executed after a "Save" button is clicked.

Comment: @JonLachonis right. If you run this code before the sorting happens, it will always run on the original order. If you run it after the sort, it'll run on the new order. **The code you have written will only run once, it won't re-run when the order changes unless you tell it to.**

Comment: It doesn't get the new order. That's the issue.

Comment: Added the click event for clarity.  So if things are re-ordered and save-button is clicked, it doesn't get the new order.

Comment: Please show full code. I test at http://jsbin.com/qoqomobodi/1/ - it's works fine

Comment: And one more question - how do you know than new order didn't applyed? Indexes ( in your code ) will always start from 0 and go as 1, 2, 3 - you should look at elements

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle demonstrating this working http://jsfiddle.net/tgz0utr1/

```
<div id="element-destination">
    <ol>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ol>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="save-button"/>
<div id="print-order">
</div>

<script>
    $(function() {
      $('#save-button').click(function(event) {  
         $('#print-order').html("");
         $('li').each(function(index) { 

           $('#print-order').append($(this).html()+"<br/>");

         });
      });

      $('ol').sortable();
      $('ol').disableSelection();
    });
</script>
```